# Executing same request from C# VS SSMS give different execution time

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-tuning

I have a request like this one

```
SELECT 
[EstimateId], 
[CreationUserId], 
[EstimateStatusValueId], 
[LanguageId], 
[LocationId], 
[EstimatorUserId], 
[FilterUnitSystemTypeId], 
[EstimateNumber], 
[RevisionNumber], 
[CreationDate], 
[ModificationDate], 
[ProjectDescription], 
[IsBsdq], 
[ClosingDate], 
[ClosingTime], 
[ClosingUpdatedOn], 
[DeadLineDate], 
[IsReceived], 
[Inclusion], 
[Exclusion], 
[Misc], 
[Note], 
[WorkDeadLines], 
[Comments], 
[Validity], 
[PlansLocation], 
[PlansReceivedFrom], 
[Price]
FROM [Estimate].[Estimates] 
ORDER BY [ClosingDate] ASC, [ClosingTime] ASC
```

When i run this query in SSMS i get a executing time of 953ms, but when i run this query from a Linq Query in my C# i get a executing time of 1813ms.

The Linq Query use the ".Net SqlClient Data Provider" and is issued against EntityFramework (EDMX file). Is this can be an issue ?

Does anybody knows why i have a big difference between execution times of those requests that are the same but execute from different context against the same database ?

I verified all execution plans of both request and they use the same index to satisfy their respective query.

To see the execution plan of the C# request i use the SQL profiler to trap the Show Plan XML event and i compare it to the one of SSMS and both are the same.

Comment: just a small question - why are you selecting all table's data without any search condition? Do you really need all the data in the application without any filtering?

Comment: Yes this is a feature that i need but this feature will not be use often. I know that is not optimal to issue a big query without where clause.

Comment: Anyway my concern is not the request itself but the difference between executing times. I show you this query but all queries give similar results. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is in the EDMX file use to generate queries from the C# app.

I found those links that explain the case.

[Code Project](http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/database/PerfEntityFramework.aspx?msg=3500412)

[Stackoverflow-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147749/entity-framework-all-tables-in-one-edmx-file)

[Stackoverflow-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867479/entity-framework-4-does-it-make-sense-to-create-a-single-diagram-for-all-entitie/3868075#3868075)

Answer (score 6):

Is this consistent, time after time?

I see a CPU difference which could be compile time. Are there any LINQ settings that affect this?

Edit:

- Capture the plans in Profiler
- Are you sure the SQL is the same *in Profiler*?

Comment: Yes it's consistent time after time. I don't know for linq settings. but i found this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/linqsql2.aspx

Comment: You can see the plan in picture above for both query. Yes i am sure the SQL is the same in profiler. SQL, Profiler, SSMS and C# app are all hosted on my computer for development purpose.

Comment: Capture the *actual plan* in XML from Profiler. Not from cache. You have different responses but you show a different plan = wrong plan shown above maybe

Answer (score 3):

You will want to look at the Execution plans for the two queries and see where they are different.

Comment: i just edit my post... and i already verify that both query use same plan.

Comment: That's the profiler capture, not the execution plan.  You'll want to add the SQL Plan XML object in profiler.  Take the XML and save it to a file with the extension .sqlplan.  Then double click on the file to view the plan in SSMS.  You can post the plans here if you'd like.

Comment: I just add the event you told me into profiler and it's the same as my last request that i post in my question. I got the same plans.. any other idea ...

Comment: Everything looks correct. The only thing which might explain it would be if the .NET application doesn't receive the data quickly enough.  The time reported in SQL Profiler includes the amount of time to transfer the data from the server to the client. So if the client doesn't download everything quickly enough the run time reported will be longer.

Comment: thanks for the help but those tests were made on the same machine as the server itself ! Weird. :(

Comment: Then is comes down to what the application is doing with the data, and how it is reading the data from the database.

Comment: @Nico ~ We would need to see the C# code that is consuming this query to help you more. We don't need the whole program, just an idea of how the data is getting read. Pure ADO.NET? LINQ? Something else? An ORM?

Comment: In support to mrdenny's answer I'd add that I tested a query in 3 different SQL clients and their reported times were all different although the IO statistics and execution the plans were identical. It was all caused by the internal way of how the clients treated the data. I believe that you can get different time results by outputting to a file, to the grid in Management Studio or to the text output.

Anyway, from what I remember, the documentation said that SQL will always be faster than LINQ to SQL, so this is not a surprise :-).